# Do something when li/td has a span

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

i have a small problem. Want to fadeIn tolltip as a span on mouseenter action, when this span element is on td. So i need to check every td element and fadeIn span if it's actually exist inside. So this is my code. Thx for help...

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.winners_calendar td').mouseenter(function(){
        if($('.winners_calendar td').find('span').length == 1){
            $('.tooltip_paragon').stop(1,1).fadeIn('300');
        }
    });
    $('.winners_calendar td').mouseleave(function(){
        if($('.winners_calendar td').find('span').length == 1){
            $('.tooltip_paragon').stop(1,1).fadeOut('300');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.winners_calendar td').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.tooltip_paragon',this).stop(true,true).fadeIn(300);
    });
    $('.winners_calendar td').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.tooltip_paragon',this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

It only fades in the tooltip for the hovered row if it exists.

or you can shorten it with:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.winners_calendar td').hover(function(){
        $('.tooltip_paragon',this).stop(true,true).fadeToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the title, let alone the question, so +1 for getting considerably further than me.